# Localization in Noetherian rings

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian ring with no nonzero nilpotents. Is every localization of $R$ at a maximal ideal a field?

Comment: Are you adding your thoughts soon? Just a problem statement is likely to attract a lot of negative attention. There is still time to ward off such problems.

Comment: I think you mean "at a minimal prime ideal". Because localizing at a maximal ideal (in a ring of positive dimension) makes no sense, if you want the result to be a field .

Answer (score 1):

For a field $F$, the ring of power series $F [[x]]$ is a Noetherian local domain.

Check against this example.

If you don't like power series, just take any Notherian domain and localize at a nonzero prime and  look at the result as a candidate. Localizations of Noetherian rings are Noetherian.

---

Bonus:

Among commutative rings, the condition of having all localizations at maximal ideals result in fields [characterizes von Neumann regular rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring#Facts). Such rings do not have nonzero nilpotents, of course, but there are reduced rings that aren't VNR.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true, when we localize such a ring at a minimal prime ideal.

Let $P$ be a minimal prime ideal of $R$. $PR_P$ is the only prime ideal of $R_P$, hence equal to the nil radical. Let $x \in PR_P$. We deduce $x^n=0$ for some $n > 0$. By the definition of localization, there is $s \notin P$ satisfying $sx^n=0$. In particular $sx$ is nilpotent in $R$, thus we deduce $sx=0$ by assumption and therefore $x=0$ in $R_P$. This shows $PR_P=0$, so $R_P$ is a field, since the zero ideal is the maximal ideal.